# JPA Eclipselink JOIN FETCH LAZY relation returning null

Tags: jpa, null, eclipselink, lazy-loading, fetch

I am always getting NULL from a JOIN FETCH clause in my JPA Query, even though I have everything configured as expected:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_BANNER_IMAGE")
public class BannerImage extends BaseEntity<Integer> {      
    protected FileReference fileReference;
    private String type;
    private String labelTitle;  

    protected BannerImage() {}

    @Id    
    @TableGenerator(name="genBannerImage", table="TB_ID_GENERATOR",
            pkColumnName="ID_NAME", valueColumnName="ID_VAL",
            pkColumnValue="TB_BANNER_IMAGE", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="genBannerImage")
    @Column(name = "ID_BANNER_IMAGE", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    @Column(name="TYPE")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_FILE_REFERENCE", nullable=false)
    public FileReference getFileReference() {
        return fileReference;
    }

    public void setFileReference(FileReference fileReference) {
        this.fileReference = fileReference;
    }

    @Column(name="LABEL_TITLE")
    public String getLabelTitle() {
        return labelTitle;
    }

    public void setLabelTitle(String labelTitle) {
        this.labelTitle = labelTitle;
    }
}
```

for File Reference Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_FILE_REFERENCE")
public class FileReference extends BaseNamedEntity<String> {

    private String type;

    public FileReference() {}

    @Id    
    @TableGenerator(name="genFileReference", table="TB_ID_GENERATOR",
            pkColumnName="ID_NAME", valueColumnName="ID_VAL",
            pkColumnValue="TB_FILE_REFERENCE", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="genFileReference")
    @Column(name = "ID_FILE_REFERENCE", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
    @Override
    public void setId(String id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }       
}
```

Service class:

```
@Path("/banner")
public class BannerImageService extends BaseServiceFacade<BannerImage, Integer> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Crud<BannerImage, Integer> lookupService() throws ServiceLocatorException {          
        return ServiceLocator.getInstance()
                .getLocalHome(ServicesConstants.BANNER_IMAGE_SERVICE);      
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDefaultGetQuery() {
        return BannerImageDAO.GET_BY_ID_FETCH_FILE_REF;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDefaultQuery() {
        return BannerImageDAO.GET_ALL_FETCH_FILE_REF;
    }    
}
```

get REST method of BaseServiceFacade:

```
@Override
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/{id}")
public T get(@PathParam("id") ID id) {
    try {
        if (!validateID(id)) {
            logMessage("Invalid Entity ID: " + id);
            return null;    
        }           

        String defaultGetQuery = getDefaultGetQuery();
        if (defaultGetQuery != null) {
            Map<String, Object> mapParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            mapParams.put("id", id);
            List<T> entityList = getService().search(defaultGetQuery, mapParams);
            if (entityList != null && entityList.size() == 1) {
                T ent = entityList.get(0);
                return ent;
            } else {
                logMessage("Invalid search by Entity ID: " + id);
            }

        } else {                
            return getService().findById(clazz, id);    
        }           

} catch (ServiceException e) {
    serviceException(e);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logException(ex);
}
    return null;
}
```

And finally the Service Bean EJB which reads from entityManager:

```
public class BaseServiceBean<T extends IEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> implements Crud<T,ID> {

        // ... generic methods to be reused by subclasses

        @Override
        public List<T> search(String queryOrNamedQuery) throws ServiceException {
            return search(queryOrNamedQuery, null, 0, 0);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<T> search(String namedQueryOrHql, Map<String, Object> parameters, int start, int chunkSize) {
            try {
                Query query = createQuery(namedQueryOrHql, getQueryType(namedQueryOrHql));
                if (start > 0) {
                    query.setFirstResult(start);
                }
                if (chunkSize > 0) {
                    query.setMaxResults(chunkSize);
                }
                addParameters(query, parameters);
                List<T> result = query.getResultList();
                afterSearch(result); 
                return result;

            } catch (NoResultException nre) {
                nre.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                cce.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();            
            }
            return null;
        }

    protected void afterSearch(List<T> result) {

    }
// etc...
```

implementation specific class for BannerImageService:

```
    @Stateless(mappedName="ejb/BannerImageService")
    public class BannerImageServiceBean extends BaseServiceBean<BannerImage, Integer> implements BannerImageServiceBeanRemote, BannerImageServiceBeanLocal {

    @Override
    protected void afterSearch(List<BannerImage> result) {

        if (result != null && result.size() == 1) {         
            BannerImage bannerImage = result.get(0);
            bannerImage.getFileReference();
        }

        super.afterSearch(result);
    }

// additional code ...
```

When I try to fetch my BannerImage class together with it's corresponding FileReference member I always get NULL even though in my DB there is an existing foreign key present:

JPQL:

```
"SELECT a FROM BannerImage a join fetch a.fileReference WHERE a.id = :id";
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT t1.ID_BANNER_IMAGE, t1.LABEL_TEXT, t1.LABEL_TITLE, t1.TYPE, 
t1.ID_FILE_REFERENCE, t0.ID_FILE_REFERENCE, t0.NAME, 
t0.TYPE FROM TB_FILE_REFERENCE t0, TB_BANNER_IMAGE 
t1 WHERE (t0.ID_FILE_REFERENCE = t1.ID_FILE_REFERENCE) AND t1.ID_BANNER_IMAGE = 1
```

in my DB the record shows a correct reference:

```
BANNER_IMAGE:

1;"";"main";"2bdbb063d0d0ee2939c89763945d9d9e";"banner1.png";"image/png"
```

If I execute :

```
select * from TB_FILE_REFERENCE where ID_FILE_REFERENCE = '2bdbb063d0d0ee2939c89763945d9d9e'
```

I can find the record in the DB, although my EclipseLink JPA Implementation always returns null:

[image]

EclipseLink Version 2.5.2-M1

This is how the Entity gets passed from Service Layer to the

Can someone help pointing why the JOIN FETCH is not properly working?

Comment: Check what happens if you use the accessor methods on it rather than inspecting the field in a debugger.  Weaving lazy relationships means the field isn't populated until it is accessed.  You can check that fetch joins work by checking the SQL issued when accessing the lazy relationship - if SQL is issued to query for it, something is wrong.

Comment: Whenever I try to do a getFileReference() I get:  [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization

Comment: This means the entity was serialized so that the factory is no longer available to read the relationship.  What version of Eclipselink are you using, and can you show the code you are using to read in the entity?  Have you read in the entity before, or is this a clear entitymanager context?

Comment: updated the question adding the info above. I read the entity from an EJB and return the result of List<T> result = query.getResultList();

Comment: what does afterSearch do?  If you just execute a simple JPQL "SELECT a FROM BannerImage a join fetch a.fileReference WHERE a.id = :id" and immediately check the fileReference, is it fetched?  The only way I can see this happening is if the returned BannerImage is refreshed which will reset indirection/lazy relationships

Comment: afterSearch is a hook method to enable the implementation specific classes (BannerImageServiceBean for example) to do something while the persistence context is still open before leaving the EJB Container boundary, it's empty by default and can be implemented by subclasses if necessary, so in this case in BannerImageServiceBean I  just "touch" the fileReference object returned and I can fetch it from the session, if I do the simple JPQL above I get a null value as fileReference.

Comment: so in this case in BannerImageServiceBean I override afterSearch and just "touch" the fileReference object returned and I can fetch it from the session, solving the problem by the meanwhile, but it's not the preferred way, so I hope I can find why the default JPQL "join fetch" is not working in this scenario.

Comment: Has anybody solved the problem? If yes please respond to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and looking closely I see that this issue was happening only to entities recently created/saved. Then I figured that it has something to do with eclipselink cache. I solved this problem by adding this line before making a join fetch JPQL query,

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM BannerImage a join fetch a.fileReference WHERE a.id = :id").getResultList();
```

HTH!